# How can I query DynamoDB table with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm new with Dynamodb and I don't get it how to make a query to this database.
The table is `ave` and the structure is:

```
{
  "abuelaMaterna": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#8308",
    "nombre": null,
    "placa": 8308
  },
  "abuelaPaterna": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#8389",
    "nombre": null,
    "placa": 8389
  },
  "abueloMaterno": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#2874",
    "nombre": "ALI",
    "placa": 2874
  },
  "abueloPaterno": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#2300",
    "nombre": "MERLOT",
    "placa": 2300
  },
  "almacen": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#1",
    "nombre": "Inventario",
    "tipo": "inventario"
  },
  "almacenes": [
    {
      "almacen": {
        "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#1",
        "nombre": "Inventario",
        "tipo": "inventario"
      },
      "fecha": 1540872000
    }
  ],
  "color": "Indio",
  "createdAt": 1540911765981,
  "disponibleCruce": true,
  "fechaNacimiento": 1534910400,
  "genero": "macho",
  "id": "12857657-d82e-4021-8a28-66edaa1bffd3",
  "madre": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#8924",
    "nombre": null,
    "placa": 8924
  },
  "marcajeColiseo": "10",
  "notas": [
    {
      "fecha": 1550588244.267,
      "nota": "Vov"
    },
    {
      "fecha": 1552922635.12,
      "nota": "Maca Lo vió y dijo que es especial no se gasta ya"
    }
  ],
  "owner": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com",
  "ownerPlaca": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#10669",
  "padre": {
    "id": "galloselcomandante-gmail.com#9127",
    "nombre": null,
    "placa": 9127
  },
  "pesos": [

  ],
  "placa": 10669,
  "tipoTuza": "Peine",
  "updatedAt": 1540911765981,
  "viva": true
}
```

The table have thousands elements and I want all the items where `owner` is equals to `example@gmail.com`
I already did a research in AWS Docs but I don't know how to make it work. I'm using 'aws-sdk` in Nodejs, I did a 'dotClient.scan' but it's not enough

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

To a look [here](https://github.com/NoSQLKnowHow/DynamoDB-SDK-examples/tree/master/node.js/WorkingWithQueries) for some examples using node.js. The problem you have with your key is that the ID looks to be a compound value. You cannot do a begins_with() on the partition key. You can on the sort key though. So you might need to rethink your schema design to put the email as the partition key and the number after the # as the sort key. Without knowing your access patterns it is difficult to say if that will create a hot key in your database.

Comment: I cannot edit the schema design, this app is already in production and I don't have nothing to do now. I still don't know how to make that query with the current schema

Comment: You can't. Query is only available on your table key. You have to either use scan, or add a Global Secondary Index that works for your case

Comment: When I did the scan this not returns all the items I don't know why. Can you show me the right way to do it? This is how I did it:```AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, region, endpoint })
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "ave",
};

docClient.scan(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    } else {        
        console.log("Total: ", result.Count, result.ScannedCount)
    }
});
 ```

Comment: Scan is limited in size of data returned. After that 1MB, you have to use pagination to get the other items in the scan.